# Хранение финансовых операций пользователя

Tags: статистика, mysql

Возник вопрос: как хранить информацию, которая будет часто изменяться. Суть такова: пользователь выполняет задания, за выполненные задания ему будет зачисляться определенная сумма денег, и нужно будет как-то сделать статистику этой информации: сумма заработанных денег за день, неделю, месяц. Так вот, как это лучше реализовать на уровне БД.

Мое решение:

1.Таблица `finance_users(id,id_user,count_suma)` - таблица, в которой будет хранится информация о текущем балансе.

2.Таблица `finance_statistic(id,id_user,suma,datetime)` - таблица, в которую будет заносится информация после выполнения каждого задания.

Посоветуйте более лучший вариант решения.

Comment: Да нормальный у вас вариант. Простая задача - простое решение.

Comment: Минус за грамматику...

Answer (score 2):

`finance_users(id, id_user, count_suma)` - count_suma хранить сумму в бд некруто=) а значит эта таблица вообще не нужна. у тебя будет просто запрос с подсчетом суммы из второй таблицы и все.

```
finance_statistic(id, id_user, suma, datetime)
```

Comment: А если я захочу обнулить свой счет, но при этом хочу знать свою статистику зароботка ?

Comment: @namak7, я правильно понял, что вы предлагаете высчитывать сумму каждый раз?

Comment: тогда вам придется писать триггер на вставку, обновление, удаление в таблице finance_statistic, м?

Comment: @red_devil тогда вот эти два поля count_suma.finance_users и suma.finance_statistic в теории у вас никак не связаны.
count_summa у вас будет жить своей жизнью...
вообще обнуления как такового быть не должно, забацайте ему просто отрицательную сумму и будет у него 0. он хотя бы будет знать когда ему обнулили=)

Comment: Вопрос чуть не по теме. Как сделать так что бы при добавлении новой записи в первую таблицу, во вторую таблицу записывался id записи первой таблици. 

users(id,login,email)
history(id,id_user,news)

Comment: mysql_insert_id()

Comment: это имелось ввиду? последний id из последнего insert'а

Comment: да, сейчас попробую.